# What dependencies does the Mobile Device Detection Rule have?

Tags: mobile

My Sitecore site has a rule to determine if the mobile version of the web site should be shown. Can anyone explain to me in detail what exactly is happening with this rule? Is there a DLL involved? Is this something that comes with Sitecore out of the box? Is this using [51Degrees](https://51degrees.com/device-detection) somehow?

[image]

I found this DLL reference:

[image]

**EDIT:**

The Screen Width Rule Element for Device Detection points to:

```
Sitecore.SharedSource.MobileDeviceDetector.Rules.Conditions.ScreenWidthCondition, Sitecore.SharedSource.MobileDeviceDetector
```

Comment: Find those conditions in content tree. In Sitecore 8 they are under `/sitecore/system/Settings/Rules/Definitions/Elements/` node. Their items will show you what code is used by them.

Comment: Sitecore.SharedSource.MobileDeviceDetector.Rules.Conditions.ScreenWidthCondition, Sitecore.SharedSource.MobileDeviceDetector

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using Mobile Device Detector module from Sitecore Marketplace ( https://marketplace.sitecore.net/modules/mobile_device_detector.aspx ).

Yes, it's using `FiftyOne.Foundation.dll` and some extra code for rules above it.

There is additional processor added to the `httpRequestBegin` pipeline called `DeviceResolver` which tries to resolve what device is used.

And `ScreenWidthCondition` uses `HttpContext.Current.Request.Browser.ScreenPixelsWidth` to determine screen value so it's not really related to anything Sitecore specific.